# Ruby instance variable and local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've always thought instance variable as used only within the definition of a class and can be accessed inside the class. When I am learning rails I am looking at an example like this:

```
class Movie
  def initialize(isbn)
    @isbn = isbn
  end
  def isbn
    @isbn
  end
end
@movie = Movie.new("0702")
@movie.isbn
```

I'm confused that a instance variable appears outside of a class definition. Why use @movie instead of local variable "movie"?

Follow up questions:

1. Since instance variables can live in a another scope, when the program need to create multiple new objects, do they all have the same name @movie? Are the new object always overwirte the old one?
2. In a larger program(like a MVC app), does the @movie shared by all the files(model, view, controller)?

Comment: You are confused for a reason, because there is no need to use an instance variable (`@movie`) in this example. A local variable (just `movie`) would be perfectly fine.

Comment: After your latest edit, your question is unfortunately off-topic for being too broad. Please only ask one, focsed question per question. If you have multiple questions, ask multiple, clearly understandable, focused, well-researched questions. Note that I have no idea what your first followup questions is trying to ask. And the second doesn't make much sense either: instance variables belong to instances, aka objects. They have nothing to do with files.

Answer (score 2):

> I've always thought instance variable as used only within the definition of a class and can be accessed inside the class.

That's wrong. Instance variables have nothing to do with classes at all. Instance variables belong to *objects* (aka *instances*), that's why they are called instance variables.

> I'm confused that a instance variable appears outside of a class definition.

It is perfectly fine for an instance variable to appear outside of a class definition. After all, the other instance variables in your example are also not inside a class definition, they are in method definitions.

> Why use @movie instead of local variable "movie"?

There is no reason to do that in the code snippet you posted. But if it were part of a larger program, there certainly could be good reasons to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables have another scope than local variables.
Outside a class you are still in the main Object class as you can see in the error produced in the following example.
So in my example if I had to use the movie variable in a method like test I need an instance variable or (better) I would need to pass it as a parameter.

In this case they are not much better than a global variable in poluting the namespace. Couldn't find a good article about Ruby and using variables and namespaces although I read them in the past. If I do, I'll add it to the answer.

```
class Movie
  def initialize(isbn)
    @isbn = isbn
  end
  def isbn
    @isbn
  end
end
@movie = Movie.new("0702")
@movie.isbn
movie = "you won't see me"

def test
  p @movie # #<Movie:0x00000002d1e7f8 @isbn="0702">
  p movie # error undefined local variable or method `movie' for main:Object
end

test
```

Answer (score -3):

You are confusing class instance and instance variable. Class instance (also sometimes referred to as Object) is what `@movie` is in your example.

To put it in other words, you initialize/ instantiate a class when you do Class.new (`Movie.new` above) there by creating a new instance of movie.

`isbn` on the other hand is an instance variable (also referred to as member variable sometimes) as it is defined within the class `Movie` and accessible to each instance of that class. The reason it is called an instance variable is because each instance of class movie – say you have another instance called `@movie2 = Movie.new("1234")` it will have its own copy of `@isbn` with the value 1234

an instance variable is a variable defined in a class (i.e. a member variable), for which each instantiated object of the class has a separate copy, or instance